# How to create a trail like this in Unity?

Tags: unity

I want to create a trail like this game...

When the plane flies it creates this trail...

[image]

It's possible because the game itself was made in Unity...

But I can't find any options to do so...

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Google "unity particle system". That is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Unity's [Trail Renderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html).

Comment: so, trail renderer can do it?

Comment: Yeah, that is why I suggested you look into the Trail Renderer component.  It does exactly this.  If the functionality is not good enough, you could always extend it to your likings, or write your own.